# Can't download sources (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Whenever the m2eclipse plugin wants to download the source files of a Maven dependency I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.attachSourcesAndJavadoc(BuildPathManager.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.run(DownloadSourcesJob.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Do you know what the problem could be?

---

According to the [source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/plain/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/src/org/eclipse/m2e/jdt/internal/BuildPathManager.java) the problem seems to be in this line:

```
      cp[i] = JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(entry.getPath(), srcPath, null, entry.getAccessRules(), //
          attributes.toArray(new IClasspathAttribute[attributes.size()]), // 
          entry.isExported());
```

---

I'm using the new Eclipse Indigo with the current Maven version.

Comment: This seems more like a bug that a typical SO question.  I'd recommend raising a bug on bugzilla for this, or sending a message to the m2e-users mailing list.  You'd probably get a better response there.

Comment: Where are these going to be downloaded from ? Is that with all the jars or with a specific jar ? Are you behind any proxy setting.

Comment: what version of maven and m2eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I ran into a problem with a similar symptom, but totally different cause, where the entry's getPath() was returning null.

If you turn on debug output in Preferences... Maven, I suspect you'll be shown the path.

If it's just one jar, you might check the dependency's pom and then check to see if the source jar is where it should be.  It shouldn't blow up like this, of course, but stranger things have happened.